# 5V relay with Raspberry pi 3 Model B

Tags: gpio, pi-3, home-automation, relay, output

I am working on home Automation Project (Voice Recognition to light On/Off)
and yes i'm new to raspberry pi

I have:

- [ http://www.amazon.in/Raspberry-Pi-64-bit-quad-core-Cortex/dp/B01CCOXV34?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00 ]
- [ http://www.amazon.in/channel-control-module-optocoupler-arduino/dp/B00KTELP3I?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00 ]

Can i use this relay with raspberry pi ?? (Gpio o/p is 3v right?)

and i also want some suggestions regarding this project.... i would really appreciate.. Thank You..

Comment: this question has been asked and answered here: [Power a 5V relay from GPIO pins](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27928/power-a-5v-relay-from-gpio-pins)

Comment: Probably not as it claims "Each one needs 15-20mA Driver Current". You will find lots of similar questions on this site. You are unlikely to get suggestions - this is a Question and Answer site See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @JoePlatano not duplicate as the device apparently uses opto-isolators. Still not a great question.