# How can a simple NPN step up from 3.3 to 5, without 5V in picture?

Tags: relay

[image: Image of Circuit]

I've come across this circuit to common pi problem of stepping up 3.3 GPIO to 5V, so it could drive a relay module (Link [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=197339)). I've one doubt, most circuits online also have a 5V input in the circuit, like so from [link here](https://iot-playground.com/blog/2-uncategorised/40-esp8266-wifi-relay-switch-arduino-ide):

[image]

Of course my understanding is limited, since I'm a noob when it comes to circuits, how would the first circuit work (how it outputs 5V to relay pin LN1)?

EDIT1:

My relay board is like so: [image]

Comment: See here for how it's done https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28201/19949

Comment: The +5V in your schematic is not being produced by the circuit.  It is assumed to come from an external power supply. The circuit just allows the two to interface so that the RPI can control the external +5V with a 3.3V output to turn on the relay.

Comment: Most relay modules have onboard drivers and/or optoisolators (as the item pictured appears to have). You **DO NOT** need 5V to drive them or a transistor, although the relay itself does need 5V.

Comment: @Milliways So are you saying the first image would work as is? When you say as the item pictured appears to have, which item are you referring to? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Milliways When you say I dont even need a transistor, then where on the relay board should I put the GPIO Output ? If it was put in relay pin LN1, then the problem would not even have happened for the two links I've mentioned. So I'm thinking there must be some other place to put it?

Comment: If you want more detail, you need to provide details of the relay board you are using, because there are many different devices. Edit into your question NOT comments.

Comment: @Milliways Why dont you assume the same relay module as in link 1, because thats what I have too. I've put the relay board image in question. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jamboree I read most posts; I don't read all links - this is **YOUR** question - it is up to you to make it complete. The people who answer are volunteers who are prepared anyone who makes a fair effort. The link is to a picture, which is useless, you need a specification.