# External power supply to a relay controlled by a Raspberry Pi

Tags: relay

I am a beginner to relays and Raspberry Pi so please pardon me if my question sounds naive. I am trying to control 4 DC motors using relays and raspberry pi. I have decided to use an external supply for the relay. My doubt is how to connect the external power supply with the relay. I know that connecting the JD-VCC and GND to the external power supply would allow to me power the relay separately but I have also seen videos where the external power supply is directly connected NO pin of each of the relay. Image shown for reference:
[image: Power source directly connected to relay]

Sorry for the poor image quality but the youtube video showing the connection is shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xc1daIb1LVc). I wanted if there is a difference between connection as shown in the image and connecting the supply to JD-VCC and GND. Also which is the best way to do it. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi @Prashant, your question about JD-VCC is a bit complicated.  You might like to read the following to get started: (1) Appendix C of my answer to the question: ( https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99988/how-to-wire-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-16-channel-relay-module-it-wont-work ),  (2) The paragraphs on using the Forbes recommended relay of my answer to the following question: ( https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95862/relay-status-leds-are-blinking-but-the-relay-coil-is-not-activating ) / continue, ...

Comment: Now let us look at the Rpi JD-Vcc connection schematic, as shown in my second answer referred above: ( https://imgur.com/gallery/DVohaVG ) You need to read the schematic very carefully for at least 5 minutes, before I move on, ...  /to continue, ...

Comment: In the above schematic, JD-Vcc jumper is removed, and (1)  Opto coupler is  powered by 3V3, (2) Songle relay switch is powered by 5V.  Now suppose we have a similar low trigger relay, but without JD-Vcc jumper,  Or we can consider that even if we have JD-Vcc jumper, this time we insert the jumper, so that both optocoupler and relay switch are connected by 5V, as show in the following picture. (https://imgur.com/gallery/GwBdP5Y )  /to continue, ...